# How return the same class type instance

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have List<T> generic class. The question is how to create the "filter" method that should return a new instance of the same List<T> class.

```
   class List<T> {
      protected items: Array<T>
    
      constructor() {
        this.items = []
      }
    
      add(value: T): void {
        this.items.push(value)
      }
    
      // ....
    
      filter (condition: any): List<T> {
        // filter this.items
        // and return new instance of the same List<T> type 
    
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself to solve this problem?  Do you have any experience `filter`ing an array and constructing a `new` instance of a class?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, what is `condition`?  The `any` type is too loose to be useful here.  I would assume that it's a callback of the form `(elem: T) => boolean`, but if you don't say that, someone like @aptlyundecided might come by and assume that it's a value of type `T` and try to test it with `===`.  What's the use case here?  Like, the real world scenario this is solving?  (If the answer is "a homework question", then I guess we'd need the full question)

Comment: By *"a new instance of the same List<T> class"* , do you mean that if you have a subclass of `List<T>` then it should be a new instance the same subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it would make it easier if you would have a constructor for the List which takes the items as a parameter.

```js
constructor(items?: T[]) {
  this.items = items ?? [];
}
```

Then filtering is easy since `Array.prototype.filter` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) is basically exactly what you would want to use here:

```js
filter(condition: (i: T) => boolean): List<T> {
  return new List(this.items.filter(condition));
}
```

If you don't want to change the constructor this would be the solution:

```js
filter(condition: (i: T) => boolean): List<T> {
  const list = new List<T>();

  for (const item of items) {
    if (condition(item)) {
      list.add(item);
    }
  }

  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for?

This is the most generic way I could think of doing it while keeping the items variable to be "read-only".

```
class List<T> {
  protected items: Array<T>;

  constructor(itemList?: Array<T>) {
    this.items = []

    // conditionally initialize with set of data
    if (itemList) {
      itemList.forEach((i: any) => {
        this.add(i);
      });
    }
  }

  add(value: T): void {
    this.items.push(value)
  }

  filter (condition: any): List<T> {
    const filteredItems = this.items.filter((t: T) => {
      return t === condition
    });
        
    return new List(filteredItems);
  }
}
```

Comment: `t === condition` is probably not very helpful here, since this will rarely ever be a true condition and it's much more generic to pass a predicate function to the filter function.